# Update cookie value in Laravel 4

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4

Let's say that I wan't a cookie value updated based on a query string parameter. Despite the fact that I change the value of the query string parameter, the value of the cookie is not updated; it stays the same all the time.

```
Route::get('cookie', function(){

        print_r(Cookie::get('testcookie', null));

        $cookie = Cookie::make('testcookie', Input::get('id'), 50);

        return Response::make()->withCookie($cookie);
});
```

Now if I go to:

laravel.localhost/cookie?id=1

I will get null (no cookie exists in the beginning)

and then again

laravel.localhost/cookie?id=1

I will get output: 1

If I now go to

laravel.localhost/cookie?id=2

I will still get 1

How can I get this cookie to update it's value?

Comment: It should be fine, you're printing cookie before changing it. Try checking cookie value in a browser's developer tools.

Comment: No it is not. The value remains 1, no matter how many times you refresh the page with a different query string param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you're printing the 'testcookie' cookie before returning the response. The response header is already being sent via your print_r, which is keeping the cookie from functioning the way you're expecting.

Try printing the cookie in your view instead.